# What's the correct way to integrate ReactJS in a Rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, reactjs, browserify

I am looking for the right way to integrate ReactJS in a Rails app. It is very easy to use react components with the [react-rails](https://github.com/reactjs/react-rails) gem. Until I use my own components everything works fine.

It becomes interesting when you integrate 3rd party components. Often those are available as npm module. So I integrated [Browserify](http://browserify.org) to handle dependencies within modules. Here I often get weird errors. For instance I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_currentElement' of null` when I am trying to integrate [Griddle](http://griddlegriddle.github.io/Griddle/index.html).

I made a small [example Rails app](https://github.com/MMore/react-rails-example) of the current setup. There you see that my own component works, but a 3rd party not.

So where is the mistake or what's the way to integrate ReactJS in a Rails application?

Comment: Good advice from the recent RailsConf (the last 5 minutes or so discusses integration):  http://confreaks.tv/videos/railsconf2015-react-js-on-rails

Comment: Ok, so the idea is to use https://rails-assets.org which used bower to generate gems. I will test it, but unfortunately Griddle is not yet available there.

Comment: Thanks. Rails-assets seems to be the best fit for me!

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Rails with React, but only for client side apps (not for server side rendering).

In my workflow, my components use the assets pipeline resolver to define dependencies with other files/components/libraries. That is, at the top of my files you see these sort of imports:

```
//= require my/path/to/componentA
//= require my/path/to/componentB
```

Whenever I need a library (I am using React Bootstrap, for instance) I just go the github of such library and download the file that is normally under /build or even on the root of the project.

It really sucks not to have a better way to download dependencies in any other way.

In my environment, I needed to do some stuff with my React files (I am using [React Templates](http://wix.github.io/react-templates/)), so I have kind of an hybrid in Rails/Grunt. Most of the things are served by Rails, but in the middle, there's a grunt server processing my HTML files (ReactTemplates's code) that are then compiled to JavaScript.

I am not so happy with this approach, but could not find another way, as Rails seems to be kind of abandoned by developers of React's extensions.

Comment: So you keep your components in the global namespace. I want a clean separation. Do you just copy 3rd party components or do you use sth like bower?